# Can I compile/package a Node-Webkit (NW.js) app into an exe for windows and a version for Linux?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, nw.js

I've looked on the Node-Webkit site and it appears to say that I can make an application with HTML5 and compile it for Windows, Linux of Mac so it will run without the need for the user to install Node.js separately. However, when I try their sample apps (e.g. https://github.com/leanote/desktop-app found on the official NW.js page: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/List-of-apps-and-companies-using-nw.js ), the ".exe" file does not run the app (on either Win 7 or XP). It just opens a simple browser window with the address "nw:blank" and a gray page says "NW.JS" and does nothing.

Can these apps be packaged and run without requiring the user to install node.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/leanote/desktop-app 's nw folder is not the distribute leanote app, it's just the NW. You must build the desktop-app. The README has written **How to build it**, **How to develop it**

You can download the distributed version via: https://github.com/leanote/desktop-app/releases

Answer (score 2):

You might try... [node-webkit-builder](https://github.com/nwjs/nw-builder) ... which is supposed to build a huge .EXE file which is self-contained for you.  Otherwise, the instructions for distributing... [how to package and distribute](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps), see Step 2b.

Comment: Thank you. I tried running the module for "node-webkit-builder" as specified here: https://github.com/mllrsohn/node-webkit-builder by putting that module code into a file called `build.js` (and altering the file path) and running the command `node build.js` but it throws an error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier...`. Do you know what might be wrong? Am I running that module incorrectly?